# Android achartengine FillOutsideLine in front of the first series and after last

Tags: android, achartengine

I need to change the color of these white rectangles on the beginning and end of the graph to the color of the first and last part of the graph (FillOutsideLine ...)

[image: graph]

But looks that it is possible to fill only part of the graph where data are shown.
TimeChart is used.
Any idea how to do it ?

EDIT:
this is the used code:
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        XYSeriesRenderer rValues = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        XYSeriesRenderer rData = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        rValues.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        rValues.setLineWidth(3);
        rValues.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        rValues.setFillPoints(true);
        rValues.setDisplayChartValues(false);
        rData.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        rData.setDisplayChartValues(false);

```
    if (data != null && data.size() > 1) {
        for (Item c : data) {
            FillOutsideLine fill1 = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.ABOVE);
            FillOutsideLine fill2 = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.BELOW);
            fill1.setFillRange(c.getRange());
            fill2.setFillRange(c.getRange());
            fill1.setColor(myColor[c.getColorId()]);
            fill2.setColor(myColor[c.getColorId()]);

            if (mDataset.getSeriesCount() == 1) {
                rValues.addFillOutsideLine(fill1);
                rValues.addFillOutsideLine(fill2);
            } else {
                rData.addFillOutsideLine(fill1);
                rData.addFillOutsideLine(fill2);
            }
        }
    } 

    if (mDataset.getSeriesCount() > 1) {
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(rData);
    }
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(rValues);
```

Comment: http://jaxenter.com/effort-free-graphs-on-android-with-achartengine-46199.html

Comment: Can u show what are u doing ?

Comment: I have added to our copy of AchartEngine the ability to set the boundary of addFillOutsideLine() to something other than the horizon line. HMU if anyone wants to help productize my hack.